# How to build a list of words from a multi line string?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a .txt file consisting of a poem. Want to take that file and for each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program is supposed build a list of words.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
try:
    fh = open(fname)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened:', fname)
    quit()
for i in fh:
    newstrng = i.rstrip()
    #print(newstrng)
justwords = newstrng.splitlines()
print(justwords)
```

The original text looks like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

When I run my code, I only get the words of line1 in a list:

```
['line1_word1', 'line1_word2', 'line1_word3', 'line1_word4']
```

Is there a way to get all the words from each line in one list, like:

```
['line1_word1', 'line1_word2', 'line1_word3', 'line1_word4', 'line2_word1', 'line2_word2', '....', line4_word3', 'line4_word4']
```

Comment: you are only splitting the line after you process all lines indent your last 2 lines so they occur inside the loop so you split and print each line

Answer (score 3):

Try to declare a list first and then read a line, split it and add it to the declared list using `extend`

```
justwords = []

for i in fh:
    newstrng = i.rstrip()
    justwords.extend(newstrng.split())
print(justwords)
```

In your code by the end of the loop `newstrng` holds only the last line. So you got `justwords` with words in that line

Comment: Thanks, but this code returns a list of strings (1 string represents one line). The desired outcome is a list of strings, one string representing one word (all words in all lines).

Comment: @LinaLinutina, just replace the `splitlines()` to `split()`